# Better code for PHP associative array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I make this compact?

```
function cake_decode( ) {

$n = "BB-005";
$arr_cake_code = array(
"GR" => "Groom's Cake",
"WD" => "Deluxe Cake",
"WC" => "Custom Cake",
"BR" => "Bridal Shower Cake",
"BB" => "Baby Shower Cake",
"RC" => "Religious Cake",
"ST" => "Sport Themes Cake",
"SP" => "Special Occasion Cake",
"GC" => "Graduation Cake",
"CB" => "Child Birthday Cake",
"BD" => "Adult Birthday Cake",
"AN" => "Anniversary Cake",
"VC" => "Valentine's Day Cake",
"THX" => "Thanksgiving Cake",
"NY" => "New Year's Cake",
"HC" => "Easter Cake",
"HW" => "Halloween Cake",
"CH" => "Christmas Cake",
"JC" => "4th of July Cake",
"CC" => "Dessert",
"CO" => "Corporate Cake",
"SC" => "Scene Cake"
);

//split $n
$o = explode("-", $n);
$p = $arr_cake_code[$o[0]];
echo "$p: $n";
}
```

cake_decode($n);

Comment: echo "Baby Shower Cake: BB-005"; *grin*

Comment: Don't try and make micro optimisations, you have bigger things to worry about!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is shorter:

```
$arr_cake_code = array(
"GR" => "Groom's",
"WD" => "Deluxe",
"WC" => "Custom",
"BR" => "Bridal Shower",
"BB" => "Baby Shower",
"RC" => "Religious",
"ST" => "Sport Themes",
"SP" => "Special Occasion",
"GC" => "Graduation",
"CB" => "Child Birthday",
"BD" => "Adult Birthday",
"AN" => "Anniversary",
"VC" => "Valentine's Day",
"THX" => "Thanksgiving",
"NY" => "New Year's",
"HC" => "Easter",
"HW" => "Halloween",
"CH" => "Christmas",
"JC" => "4th of July",
"CC" => "Dessert",
"CO" => "Corporate",
"SC" => "Scene"
);

array_walk($arr_cake_code, function(&$item, $key) { $item=$item . " Cake" });
```

But seriously... don't bother.  It's about as short as it can get in your own example.

Answer (score 1):

Put your data in JSON, put it in a file, and load it from there, since it's a resource.  That'll reduce the size of your code.

Comment: What is the benefit of this? It was a stupid question, but this isn't worth doing. If the idea is to externalise the data, another file 'cakes-arra' containing return array(...); and $arr_cake_code = include('cakes-array') would be far more efficient and easier to implement.

Comment: @David: It answers the OP's question as to how to make the code more compact.  They didn't specify the quantity of effort expected to go into it.